# Duplicated data in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

In my database the duplicates of data showing up. But this is not what i want. I want off every datatype 1 and not 2. this is my code:

for dim_cinema in processed_response:

```
# "Cinema" dimension
cinema = str(dim_cinema["cinema"])
cinema_location = str(dim_cinema["cinema_location"])

if cinema == None:
    cinema_location == None

# Check whether this record already exists in the dimension we created.
# We do this, because we don't have to insert it twice.
cursor.execute ("""
SELECT * FROM dim_cinema
WHERE cinema_name = '"""+cinema+"""'
AND cinema_location = '"""+cinema_location+""""'
""")

if cursor.rowcount == 0:
    # We don't have this combination in our dimension. Lets insert it!
    sql = """
    INSERT INTO dim_cinema (cinema_name, cinema_location)
    VALUES ('"""+cinema+"""', '"""+cinema_location+"""')
    """
    
    try:
        # Execute the SQL command and commit our changes to the database...
        cursor.execute(sql)
        print (cinema, cinema_location)
        db.commit()
        
    except:
        # Unless something goes wrong, in which case we do a rollback on our changes.
        db.rollback()
```

Comment: SQL INJECTION WARNING! **Never** construct queries using string interpolation. The library you're using should provide a way to make *parameterized queries*. Constructing queries with string interpolation is a major security flaw for your application.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? Because its a school assignment

Comment: There is the `DISTINCT` keyword that removes duplicates.

Comment: You shouldn't use `+`, `%`, f-strings, or `format` on strings to create SQL queries. If it's a school assignment, it isn't that dangerous, but they should have explained this somewhere.

Comment: AH oke, but can you help me to remove my duplicated data?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean as I don't know what library you're using or what "datatype 1 and 2" is, but adding the `DISTINCT` keyword before the columns in the SQL query that's problematic will remove duplicates.